# Identify PID from the ps -ef | grep processName

Tags: linux

I want to find my `oracle weblogic` server instance and kill it. When I find the `pid` I get below. I want to be clear what are these two ids? which one is the correct MyServer process id?

```
[oracle@xxx ~]$ ps -ef | grep MyServer
oracle    4886  4851  0 16:04 pts/2    00:00:00 grep MyServer
oracle   21759 21700  2 Sep29 ?        09:39:59 /usr/app/oracle/product/jrockit-     jdk1.6.0_29-R28.2.0-4.1.0/bin/java -jrockit -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Dweblogic.Name=MyServer...
```

Pls help me to understand what is the `4886` and `4851` here in first line of the output.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

`4886` is the PID of your own grep command, and `4851` is its parent (your shell).

But you don't need any of this stuff, because:

```
pkill -f MyServer
```

Will do the job a lot easier and more efficiently.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Correct way could be to use `pgrep`:

```
$ pgrep MyServer
```

But of course you could also exclude any lines containing the "grep" string as well:

```
$ ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep MyServer
```

The `grep -v "grep"` means "show results that don't contain string "grep" in them